# How do I get the break command to go back to my for each loop

Tags: java

I know I asked a similar question like this earlier (I figured it out though)

```
 *while(!newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guess))
                            forloop:
                        { while(!newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guess))


                    for ( String a : spaces.split("\\s"))
                    {

                        count++;

                        int x = Integer.valueOf(a);
                        if (x > guess.length())
                        {
                            System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");  
                            break innerloop;
                        }
                        if (Character.toLowerCase(newWord.charAt(x)) == letterInput.charAt(0)) 
                        {
                            //System.out.println("Guess is correct for position " + x);
                            guess = guess.substring(0, x) + letterInput + guess.substring(x + 1, guess.length());
                        }
                        if (Character.toLowerCase(newWord.charAt(x)) != letterInput.charAt(0))
                        {

                            if(count < spaces.split("\\s").length - 1)
                            {
                            break forloop;
                            }
                        }

                            if (count == spaces.split("\\s").length)

                            guesses= guesses - 1;
                            System.out.println("Your letter was not found in spaces you provided");
                            System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + guesses);
                            break;
                        }*
```

but now the break command that I have at  the third if statement after the for loop just takes me back to the loop towards the beginning of my whole code

```
*while(!newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guess))
                    innerloop:
                { while(true)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please enter the letter you want to guess");
                        String letterInput = keyboard.next();
                        letterInput = Character.toString(letterInput.charAt(0));

                        if(!Character.isLetter(letterInput.charAt(0)))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                            break;
                        }
                        if(letterInput.equalsIgnoreCase("solve"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Please solve the answer:");
                            String userSolve = keyboard.next();
                            if (!userSolve.equalsIgnoreCase(newWord))
                            {
                                System.out.println("That is not the secret word");
                                guesses = guesses - 1;
                                System.out.println("Guesses remaining: " + guesses);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("You win!");
                                System.out.println("You have guessed the word! Congratulations");
                                System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes(y) or No (n)");
                                response = keyboard.next();
                                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                                {
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                                if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
```

As you can see I placed labels on the loops I specifically want to go back to. My break is currently taking me back to my innerloop label BUT I want it to take me back to my forloop label. How exactly do I do that? I tried wrapping the for loop with while loops because thats what worked for me last time but it is not working here. Here is my whole code for reference, I apologize if its hard to read I've only started coding 2 months ago.

```
package e;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HangmanBeta{
private static final boolean testingMode = true;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    keyboard.useDelimiter("\\n"); 
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter your difficulty: Easy (e), Intermediate (i), or Hard (h)");
        String diff = keyboard.next();
        int amountOfSpaces = 0;
        String response = "";
        String guess = "";
        String newGuess = "";
        String s = "";
        int count = 0;
        String newWord = "loops";//RandomWord.newWord();

        int guesses = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < newWord.length(); i++) {
            guess = newWord.replaceAll("[^#]", "-");
        }
        if ((diff.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) || (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("i")) || (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))) {
            if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
            {
                guesses = 15;
            }
            if(diff.equalsIgnoreCase("i"))
            {
                guesses = 12;
            }
            if(diff.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))
            {
                guesses = 15;
            }
            if (testingMode == true)
            {
                System.out.println("The secret word is:" + " " + newWord);
            }
            System.out.println("The word is:" + " " + guess);

                while(!newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guess))
                    innerloop:
                { while(true)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please enter the letter you want to guess");
                        String letterInput = keyboard.next();
                        letterInput = Character.toString(letterInput.charAt(0));

                        if(!Character.isLetter(letterInput.charAt(0)))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                            break;
                        }
                        if(letterInput.equalsIgnoreCase("solve"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Please solve the answer:");
                            String userSolve = keyboard.next();
                            if (!userSolve.equalsIgnoreCase(newWord))
                            {
                                System.out.println("That is not the secret word");
                                guesses = guesses - 1;
                                System.out.println("Guesses remaining: " + guesses);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("You win!");
                                System.out.println("You have guessed the word! Congratulations");
                                System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes(y) or No (n)");
                                response = keyboard.next();
                                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                                {
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                                if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("Please enter the spaces you want to check (seperated by spaces)");
                        String spaces = keyboard.next();
                        amountOfSpaces = spaces.length();
                        if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
                        {
                            if(amountOfSpaces != 7)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                                break innerloop;
                            }

                        }
                        if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("i"))
                        {
                            if(amountOfSpaces != 5)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");   
                                break innerloop;
                            }
                        }

                        if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))
                        {
                            if(amountOfSpaces != 3)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                                break innerloop;
                            }
                        {

                            while(!newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guess))
                                forloop:
                            { while(!newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guess))


                        for ( String a : spaces.split("\\s"))
                        {

                            count++;

                            int x = Integer.valueOf(a);
                            if (x > guess.length())
                            {
                                System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                                break innerloop;
                            }

                            if (Character.toLowerCase(newWord.charAt(x)) == letterInput.charAt(0)) 
                            {
                                //System.out.println("Guess is correct for position " + x);
                                guess = guess.substring(0, x) + letterInput + guess.substring(x + 1, guess.length());

                            }
                            if (Character.toLowerCase(newWord.charAt(x)) != letterInput.charAt(0))
                            {

                                if(count < spaces.split("\\s").length - 1)
                                {
                                break forloop;
                                }


                                if (count == spaces.split("\\s").length)

                                guesses= guesses - 1;
                                System.out.println("Your letter was not found in spaces you provided");
                                System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + guesses);
                                break;
                            }

                            if (guesses == 0)
                            {
                                System.out.println("You have failed to guess the word....:(");
                                System.out.print("Would you like to play again? Yes(y) or No(n)");
                                response = keyboard.next();
                                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                                {
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                                if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            } }

                            if (newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guess))
                            {
                                System.out.println("You win!");
                                System.out.println("You have guessed the word! Congratulations");
                                System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes(y) or No (n)");
                                response = keyboard.next();
                                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                                {
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }

                            }
                        }   
                            System.out.println("Your Guess is in the word");
                        }
                        if(guesses == guesses - 1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Your letter was not found in spaces you provided");
                            System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + guesses);
                            break innerloop;

                        //System.out.print(spaces.split("\\s").length);
                        //System.out.println("Your Guess is in the word");
                        //System.out.println();
                        //System.out.println("Updated word " + guess);
                        //System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + guesses);
}
                        }
                } 

        }
    }
}

}
}
```

Comment: *"I apologize if its hard to read ..."* - Apologizing doesn't actually help.  What actually helps is making the code easier to read ... by fixing the stuff (like bad indentation, line breaks in the wrong place, lines too long, detail that is extraneous to your question) that makes the Question hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

> ... but now the break command that I have at the third if statement after the for loop just takes me back to the loop towards the beginning of my whole code.

Actually, no.

A `break` **never** takes you back.  It always takes you forward.  In this case it takes you forward to *immediately after* the block with the label that you broke.  For example:

```
while (....) {
    label: while (...) {
        ...
        if (...) break label;
        ...
    }
    // Breaks to HERE
}
```

You may then go back because of something in the context you went to.  But it is the context that does it, not the `break`.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to apply this to your example because 1) you don't explain what the code is supposed to do, 2) it is hard to figure out which of the versions you refer to, 3) the code is not compilable, and 4) the  readability issues make my head hurt.

So unless you can figure out how to make your code more readable, that is all the help I can give you.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is basically just a hangman project for my class and I'm not allowed to use arrays. The word is hidden with dashes to the user.The user has to pick a letter and the number of spaces they would like to check. The user has a certain amount of guess depending on the difficulty they choose.  If the letter they guessed is in at least one of the spaces they chose then the user loses no guesses, if the letter they guessed is in none of the spaces they chose then the user loses a guess.

Comment: I might just get rid of the whole if-statement in the for loop and repost a different question. Thanks for clarifying breaks for me though. Not sure why the code wont compile on your end, I think it might be the * stackoverflow added when I posted the code.